# Wait for all the files arrival-NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there any processor in Nifi that waits for the all the files to arrive and then put those files into HDFS.

For example:
If there are total 5 files to be fetched using SFTP but we received only 3 files, I want NiFi to wait till 5 files arrived and then put those 5 files into HDFS using PUTHDFS.

Thank you for your anwsers

Comment: maybe not possible, workaround will be schedule to process for particular interval and makesure you place all the files before the scheduled processor starts

Comment: How NIFI could know that there should be 5 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `List*` processors with a `Record Writer` and use a `MergeRecord` processor to wait for a specific number of files.

1. Use a ListSFTP processor. Set the `Record Writer` attribute. You can use anyone.
2. Connect the `success` to a `MergeRecord` processor with maximum and minimum bin sizes to set to the number of files you want to wait for.
3. Now the `merge` relation will have a single flowfile containing the file listing. Split them to individual files and process them.

Have a look at [Additional Details of ListSFTP processor](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListSFTP/additionalDetails.html). It details how you can wait for your `batch` to complete process.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, how do you know all files have arrived? Is it **always** a static 5 files?

If it is absolutely always 5 files, then just use a [MergeContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html) with a Minimum and Maximum Number of Entries set to 5. This means that all files will wait until there are exactly 5 files waiting to be merge.

But this is very inflexible to change.

Why do you need to wait for all 5 files before you put them into HDFS?

Are you trying to prevent a small files problem?

If so, you don't need to wait for all 5 files, just use a Merge and set a minimum file size to bucket files up to a minimum, with a worst-case time out.

Alternatively, the [PutHDFS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hadoop-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS/index.html) has a `Conflict Resolution Strategy` property which can be set to `append` as long as the filename is the same - you can just `UpdateAttribute` and set the filename to the same name, and then append the files whenever they arrive.